# Optional generic parameters

Tags: typescript

I have the following function

```
export function createAsyncAction<R, S>(selector: Select<S>, call: CallApi<R, S>, config: Config<R, S>): ApiAction<R, S> {
    return {
        type: '@api/ACTION',
        payload: {
            call,
            selector,
            ...config
        }
    }
};
```

For which the generic parameters `R` and `S` are automatically inferred. I'd like to keep these optional and add a few more generic parameter like so:

```
export function createAsyncAction<A, B, C, R, S>(selector: Select<S>, call: CallApi<R, S>, config: Config<A, B, C, R, S>): ApiAction<R, S> {
    return {
        type: '@api/ACTION',
        payload: {
            call,
            selector,
            ...config
        }
    }
};
```

So that I can do

```
createAsyncAction<RequestType, RequestSucces, RequestFailure>(...)
```

While still enforcing the constraints of `R` and `S` automatically. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

You can do one of two things depending on your needs:

**Add a default type for the generic parameter**

```
export function createAsyncAction<R = {}, S = {}, A = {}, B = {}, C = {}>(selector: Select<S>, call: CallApi<R, S>, config: Config<A, B, C, R, S>): ApiAction<R, S> {
    return {
        type: '@api/ACTION',
        payload: {
            call,
            selector,
            ...config
        }
    }
};
// Usage
createAsyncAction<RequestType, RequestSucces>()
createAsyncAction<RequestType, RequestSucces, ImplementationForA>()
```

**Add several overloads for the function**

This would require you to express your function signature without the extra types, you need to make the decisions of how each signature would look. For example:

```
export function createAsyncAction<R, S>(selector: Select<S>, call: CallApi<R, S>): ApiAction<any, any> 
export function createAsyncAction<A, B, C, R, S>(selector: Select<S>, call: CallApi<R, S>, config?: Config<A, B, C, R, S>): ApiAction<R, S>
// Implementation siganture, not public 
export function createAsyncAction<A, B, C, R, S>(selector: Select<S>, call: CallApi<R, S>, config?: Config<A, B, C, R, S>): ApiAction<R, S> {
...
}
```